# Alternative Proof for ${n\choose k}$ is integer

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, binomial-theorem

I have seen different type of induction proofs on this case, but trying an alternative approach I tried Induction to show that ${n\choose k}$ in binomial coefficient is an integer, where both n and k are non-negative integers.

Base case: For k = 0, ${n\choose 0}$ = 1, and is integer.

Inductive Hypothesis: For k= n-1, Assume ${n\choose n-1}$ is integer. (That's not even assumption but a fact, in fact.)

Finally, induction: For k = n, ${n\choose n}$ is integer because it's 1.

Is this a proof? Is this a thing? What is it?

Comment: It's certainly a thing. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: You should assume $\binom n {k-1}$ is an integer and prove $\binom n k$ is

Comment: If we redefined ${n\choose k}:=\frac{2(n+1)}{n+1-k}$, then all of ${n\choose 0}$, $n\choose n-1$, and ${n\choose n}$ occurring in your ... thing ... would indeed be integers. But would all $n\choose k$ be?

Comment: Before continuing... you really must define terms.  What *is* $\binom{n}{k}$ to you?  Some people *define* it to mean $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ in which case it is not immediately obvious that it is an integer.  Other people *define* it to mean the number of subsets of size $k$ from a set with $n$ elements in which case it is obvious that it is an integer as the answer to every counting question is an integer.  Other people still *define* it recursively in the usual way in which case it again is obvious that it is an integer as it is the sum of smaller integers.

Comment: Both n and k are non negative integers, editing the post now.

Comment: Read once more the comment of @JMoravitz and start with definition of $\binom nk$.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you first try inducting on $n$ rather than $k$, since each $n$ has only finitely many $k$ to check. To prove $k!|\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)$ for $n\ge k$, note $n=k$ obtains the product as $\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(k-j)=k!$, while$$\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(m+1-j)-\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(m-j)=\prod_{i=m-k+2}^{m+1}i-\prod_{i=m-k+1}^mi=k\prod_{i=m-k+2}^mi=k\frac{m!}{(m-k+1)!}.$$The inductive step works if this is a multiple of $k!$, or equivalently if $(k-1)!|\frac{m!}{(m-k+1)!}$. This tells us we can use what's called *double induction*:

- $k=0$ works since $0!=1|1=\frac{n!}{(n-0)!}$;
- If $k=l$ works for all $n$, $k=l+1$ works for $n=l+1$ by similar logic, while larger $n$ follow by the above inductvie step.

Answer (score 0):

I see a proof of the following:

Fom completely unconstrained $n$, so for instance, complex numbers.  Try it with $n = 1/2$, which shows up in the binomial expansion for the square root, $\sqrt{1+x} = \sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{1/2}{k} x^k$.

- $\binom{n}{0}$ is an integer because you say so.  Not even so much as a "$\binom{n}{0} = 1$" without justification.  At the very least, you should apply its definition so the reader can inspect that expression to validate your claim: "$\binom{n}{0} = \frac{n!}{0!(n-0)!} = 1$".
- $\binom{n}{n-1}$ is an integer because you say so, without even a pretension of proof.  Perhaps "$\binom{n}{n-1} = \frac{n!}{1!(n-1)!} = n$" would be more convincing.  This also highlights that you need to assert "$n$ is an integer" before starting these cases.
- $\binom{n}{n}$ is an integer because you say it is  $1$.  More convincing: "$\binom{n}{n} = \frac{n!}{n!0!} = 1$".

There is nothing here that shows $\binom{3}{1}$ is an integer.